# Change Struts 2, i18n classes behavior when key is not found

Tags: struts2, internationalization, jsp-tags

We used `getText` in actions, `setMessageKey` in validators and `<s:text>` in jsp files for an i18n application.

When Struts 2 could not find a key in resource bundles it returns the key itself. For example `form.transfer.confirm`.

How can we change this behavior in the way that instead of the key itself Struts2 returns empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create custom implementation of `TextProvider` and override `getText` methods in it.

1) Create class (e.g. `EmptyDefaultTextProvider`) extending one of `TextProvider` existing implementations (e.g. `TextProviderSupport`).

2) Override all `getText` methods like that:

```java
public String getText(String key, String defaultValue) {
     return super.getText(key, "");
}
```

3) Use your custom class as the default text provider. Put below in struts.xml.

```xml
<constant name="struts.xworkTextProvider" value="emptyDefaultTextProvider" />

<bean type="com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProvider" name="emptyDefaultTextProvider" 
                              class="packagepath.EmptyDefaultTextProvider" scope="default" />
```

Comment: It seems that overriding the `getText(String key, String defaultValue, List<?> args)` will make sure that all calls are overridden.

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi At least there is also `getText(String key, String defaultValue, String[] args)` and couple of `getText(String key, String defaultValue, List<?> args, ValueStack stack)`.

Comment: If you don't use struts 2's ActionSupport for your actions, the above only works if you inject the Container and then use that to inject the TextProviderFactory. See source of ActionSupport for an example.